# PATCH verb not working on android

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I have a JQM/Backbone app and using the PATCH verb with success on desktop and android browser. I am using cordova CLI 3.5.0-0.2.4 for building my apps. The problem comes only when I am executing code from within the android app. It appears that the headers don't get set correctly from within android phone.

Using chrome with the same codebase the requests look like

Remote Address:127.0.0.1:3000
Request URL:/api/v1/trucks/a9af83a594dfbbcd4b5ea23f95ac7a3f
Request Method:PATCH
Status Code:200 OK

In the app if I debug it is trying todo a POST and the route should be PATCH /api/v1/endpoint. There are no headers set to indicate a PATCH call

Any thoughts on why this is different in the cordova app on android?

Thanks.